# Как в Unity вызывать действие, если камера направляется на некий обьект (например ImageTarget)?

Tags: c#, unity3d, vuforia

Есть несколько `ImageTarget'ов`, и в интерфейсе есть три кнопки, при нажатии играет звук (озвучивание на трех языках). Как можно прикрепить действие проигрывание звука к `ImageTarget`? 
Ссылка на [GitHub](https://github.com/econordit/artestproject/tree/master/Test)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Действие проигрывания звука?, если честно из вопроса плохо понятно что у Вас не выходит

Comment: Когда через камеру находит один из объектов, например: Слон, и когда нажимаю на кнопки, должен на определенном языке озвучить (на якутском, русском, английском) и так далее.

Comment: Тоесть вы хотите, чтобы когда один из объектов, которые Вы рендерите, попал в центр экрана или определенную его область, он определялся, И менялись звуки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В задаче есть один критически важный нюанс не указанный автором: **Нужно тригерить только если мы смотрим на обьект некоторое время**

> иначе при повороте головы затригерятся слишком многие обьекты подряд -- например, все 3 аудиозаписи начнут проигрыватся одновременно

---

опробуй следующий код:

```
    using UnityEngine;

    public class VrController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        //рисовать ли луч дебага и какой длинны
        public bool DrawRay = true;
        public int RayLength = 50;

        //время срабатывания в секундах
        public float TriggerTime = 1f;


        void Update()
        {
            GameObject objWeLookOn;

            //здесь делаются всякие реакции на взгляд на обьект
            // то есть вызывать метод проигрывания звука нужно будет отсюда
            if (CheckIfWeLookOnObject(out objWeLookOn))
            {
                Debug.Log("I'm looking on" + objWeLookOn.name);
            }
        }

        //эти 2 переменные я разместил именно здесь, а не выше потому, что они
        //используются только в этом методе. Если бы использовались еще где-то
        //я бы разместил их над всеми методами
        private GameObject _lastObjWeLookedOn;
        private float _timeOfLook = 0;
        //метод возвращает тру если мы смотрим на обьект triggerTime времени и в аут запихивает сам обьект на который мы смотрим
        public bool CheckIfWeLookOnObject(out GameObject go)
        {
            RaycastHit hit;

            //рисуем луч в эдиторе если нужно для дебага
            //в рантайме видно не будет. 
            //Что бы было видно в рантайме используй lineRenderer компонет
            if (DrawRay)
            {
                Vector3 forward = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * RayLength;
                Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, forward, Color.green);
            }

            //если ни на что не смотрим -- выходим из метода
            //и обнуляем сохраненные данные
            if (!Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit))
            {
                _timeOfLook = 0;
                _lastObjWeLookedOn = null;
                go = null;
                return false;
            }

            //Проверяем на какой обьект мы смотрим
            var currObj = hit.transform.gameObject;

            //если это новый обьект, обнуляемся
            if (_lastObjWeLookedOn != currObj)
            {
                _timeOfLook = 0;
                _lastObjWeLookedOn = currObj;
            }

            //если прошел период времени -- возвращаем тру и геймобджект на который смотрим
            if (_timeOfLook > TriggerTime)
            {
                go = hit.collider.gameObject;
                _timeOfLook = 0;
                return true;
            }

            //иначе - возвращаем ничего, но считаем время т.к. мы продолжаем смотреть на этот же обьект
            go = null;
            _timeOfLook += Time.deltaTime;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Вешаешь этот скрипт себе на камеру вуфории.

Потом заменяй вывод в лог имени обьекта на нужное действие. Хоть проигрывание музыки, хоть любое другое.

Comment: В логах ничего нету, скрипт на камеру прикрепил.

Comment: Можете посмотреть https://github.com/econordit/artestproject/tree/master/Test

Comment: @AndreyZ. код работает на 100%. Я этот скрипт у себя на камере проверял. [Но без вуфории -- хотя это на практике не имеет значения].  Врубай дебаговую отрисовку линии взгляда в скрипте и проверяй в какую сторону смотрит. И не забывай что в лог кидается сообщение только если ты смотришь 1 секунду на предмет.

Comment: ну что, сделал? Сработало?

Comment: завтра отпишусь, посмотрю, спасибо

Comment: только вернулся к этому проекту, все работает, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 4):

Звуки не привязывал, т.к. не в звуках же вопрос, разбираемся как определить на что смотрит игрок:

Я написал 2 скрипта, один развесил по объектам сцены и заполнил текст разными строками, так же на эти объекты я повесил `BoxCollider`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RaycastSound : MonoBehaviour {
    public string language;
    public string sound;
}
```

Второй скрипт я повесил на камеру.

```js
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class RaycastPalyer : MonoBehaviour {

 RaycastSound prev;

 void Update () {

  RaycastHit hit;

  if (!Physics.Raycast (transform.position, transform.forward, out hit))
   return;

  RaycastSound sound = hit.collider.GetComponent<RaycastSound> ();

  if (sound == prev)
   return;
  
  prev = sound;

  if (null == sound)
   return;
  
  Debug.Log(sound.language); 
  Debug.Log(sound.sound); 

 }
}
```

Тут всю работу делает метод `Physics.Raycast` он пускает луч от камеры в направлении сцены и возвращает объект, содержащий информацию о пересечении этого луча с первым активным коллайдером, в который он упрется

В результате, когда камера смотрит на объект, в консоль выводится текст, из скриптов, которые я добавил к объектам сцены.